# Send an object from a client to a server in java

Tags: java, server, client

How do i send an object to a server in java?

Client:

```
    Help h = new Help("Mattia Cammalleri","Informatica","18 Novembre 2020");
    
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    os.writeObject(h);
    os.flush();
```

Server:

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket s = ss.accept(); 
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    Help h = (Help) is.readObject();
    System.out.println("Richiesta " + h);
```

Object (implements serializable):

```
public String alunno;
public String materia;
public String data;
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an exception? What is your console output from the `System.out.println()`?

Comment: This on th client side,
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Was the server side running when you started the client side?

Comment: yes, i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Hm, did you try to disable the firewall? Maybe also try a different port.

Comment: Now i tried to recreate the project with the same code and the error is on the server side.
With class not found exception

Comment: When you randomly change things around, we can't really help you with any new errors you are getting. There is no point in creating a new project. Nonetheless just google `ClassNotFoundException` for more information on the new issue.

Comment: On the old project i changed the port and the error (Server side) says "Connection reset".
The firewall is disabled

Comment: The error is on the line Help h = (Help) is.readObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way:

Client:

```
    Help h = new Help("Mattia Cammalleri","Informatica","18 Novembre 2020");
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    System.out.println("The object has been sent");
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(h);
    socket.close();
```

Server:

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
    System.out.println("Waiting for the client");
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected from " + socket + "!");
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    Help h = (Help) objectInputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println("Object: " + h);
    ss.close();
    socket.close();
```